# Who introduced the term Homeomorphism?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, math-history

**Who introduced the term Homeomorphism?**

I was wondering about asking this question on english.stackexchange but I think this term is strongly (and maybe solely) related to mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An excerpt from Gregory H. Moore's [The evolution of the concept of homeomorphism](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0315086006000863):

The evolution of the concept of “homeomorphism” was essentially complete by $1935$ when Pavel Aleksandrov (Paul Alexandroff) at the University of Moscow and Heinz Hopf at the Eidgenossische Technische Hochschule in Zurich published their justly famous book *Topologie*, aiming to unify the two major branches of topology, the algebraic and the set-theoretic. They took as their fundamental undefined concept “topological space,” based on the closure axioms of Kazimierz Kuratowski [$1922$]. And they defined a homeomorphism between topological spaces in the way that is now standard: “A one–one continuous mapping $f$ of a space $X$ into a space $Y$ is called a *topological mapping* or a *homeomorphism* (between $X$ and $f(X)=Y′⊆Y$) if the inverse of $f$ is a continuous mapping of $Y′$ to $X$. Two spaces… are called *homeomorphic* if they can each be mapped topologically onto each other” [Aleksandrov and Hopf, $1935$, $52$].

Comment: Thank you, that is more than I hoped for.